# Converting felt252 to ContractAddress in Cairo

Tags: starknet, zkp

How do I create a [ContractAddress](https://docs.starknet.io/documentation/architecture_and_concepts/Contracts/contract-address/) from a hex value like `0x06D98dC7ea54CF77eeD141F423f6007Dd61fbd2b6bD429Facdf5d4803353063f`?

`let addr : ContractAddress = 0x06D98dC7ea54CF77eeD141F423f6007Dd61fbd2b6bD429Facdf5d4803353063f;` is throwing an exception stating that `0x06D98dC7ea54CF77eeD141F423f6007Dd61fbd2b6bD429Facdf5d4803353063f` is considered a `felt252`.

What's the helper function to convert that Hex into a ContractAddress?

Answer (score 0):

This is the library file for that: https://github.com/starkware-libs/cairo/blob/main/corelib/src/starknet/contract_address.cairo

I believe the function `Felt252TryIntoContractAddress` would be useful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).